# python cryptography not installing pkcs7 on Apple Silicon M1 PRO

Tags: python, apple-m1

I had installed cryptography 2.9.2, but in `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography` there is not pkcs7 module. I'm running python under rosetta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the changelog and the [PKCS7](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#pkcs7) section of the documentation state that PKCS7 support was added in 3.1 and expanded in later versions. You should install a newer version.